# jquery append not works in function

Tags: jquery, function, append

i have problem with append in this function:

```
    <!-- js code here -->
    <script>
        function newAssign(divID)
        {
            $("div[id='"+divID+"']").append("<p> hello! </p>");
        }
    </script>
```

php code - call newAssign with divID onChange select

```
     <?php foreach($myvar as $each): ?>
          <select name="weekday" class="innerComboStyle" onChange="newAssign(<?php echo $each->getId() ?>);" >
                <!-- <options here... -->
          </select>
    <div id="<?php echo $each->getId() ?>" ></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I got NO ERRORs in firebug console but append not works still!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing quotes(`'`) around the argument of `newAssign` call:

```
onChange="newAssign('<?php echo $each->getId() ?>')"
```

Unless `getId()` is a number or a string `this`, not putting `'` won't work as javascript would think that you are passing a variable name. And even if it does work, it might not be as you intended.

You can instead do `$('#' + divId).append(...)`, it's easier to look at rather than using `id=`

Answer (score 0):

You need apostrophes around the id in the call, otherwise it will be interpreted as a variable name:

```
<select name="weekday" class="innerComboStyle" onChange="newAssign('<?php echo $each->getId() ?>');" >
```

---

Normally an id is unique in the page, and I suppose that you don't use an id that is not on a div, so you could just use the id in the selector:

```
$("#"+divID).append("<p> hello! </p>");
```